# Ubuntu 18.04.2 USB Mouse not being recognized

Tags: drivers, usb, mouse

### Symptoms

USB devices work, but not mice (tested 2 mice, one Logitech and one chineseium)

### Installation customizations

During installation, I used `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line in GRUB. That customization was removed once I installed the latest nVidia drivers

### Debugging/Info gathered:

`dmesg` outputs `usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd` when mouse is plugged in **after** booting, when plugged in before, nothing really shows on dmesg

`lsusb` is not aware of the device at all

Sometimes, `dmesg` would show a `not accepting address` error. This mainly disappeared when I added `pci=noaer` to stop PCIe error messages from flooding `dmesg` output

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Have you changed anything from the default installation?  It may be possible that you've blacklisted a mouse module in /etc/modules/ or made a wrong mapping in /etc/udev/  or maybe you uninstalled a kernel package.  What happens if you `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`, for example?  Please include this information in your question.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: @tudor Thanks for the followup! I included installation customizations in the question. `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` tells me I have the latest version already, and my /etc/modules/ is empty. I havent modified anything in /etc/udev/